# Netsuite: Analyzing Line before adding to Sales Order

Tags: javascript, netsuite, items

I am trying to create a popup via SuiteScript where we will show the available inventory and customer preferred brand and some other details when adding an item to an order to that the Cust Svc rep will be able to add the correct sku and ask the customer the required  questions before adding the item to the order. To do this I need to be able to access the item before its added. The popup that i have set to come now does display - but I need the qty and SKU that I am attempting to add. Current Code:

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NModuleScope Public
 *@NScriptType ClientScript
 */
define(['N/search'], runClientscript);

function runClientscript(search){
    SEARCHMODULE = search;

    function validateLine(context) {
       var currentSO = context.currentRecord;
        context.sublistId;
        if(context.sublistId == 'item'){
            alert("validateLine Triggered!");
            var cr = context.currentRecord;
        var quantityLine = currentSO.getSublistValue({
                sublistId : 'item',
                fieldId : 'quantity',
                line : 1
                });
        }
        return true; //Return true if the line insertion is valid.
    }

      /**
         * 
         * @param {object} context context object from user event.
         */
        function getLocationContext(context){
            var contextObj = {};
            contextObj.locationRecord = "customrecord_ship_priority";
            contextObj.warehouseIds = [
                {
                    name:"custrecord_nj_warehouse",
                    value:3
                },
                {
                    name:"one",
                    value:9
                },
                {
                    name:"two",
                    value:8
                },
                {
                    name:"three",
                    value:4
                }
            ]
            contextObj.parameters = getScriptParameter();
            return contextObj;
        }



    var returnObj = {};
    returnObj.validateLine = validateLine;
    return returnObj;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Please show the HTML containing the form with the quantity and SKU.

Answer (score 0):

Use `currentSo.getCurrentSublistValue({type: 'item', fieldId: '{fieldyouneedtodisplay}'})` instead, it will give the information of the item that is being added on validateline. Once you have all the infomation you need,then you can do the validation just like what pseudo code below.

```
var sItem = currentSo.getCurrentSublistText({type: 'item', fieldId: 'item'});
var nQqty = currentSo.getCurrentSublistValue({type: 'item', fieldId: 'quantity'});
//your code to validate goes after.
if(nQqty >=0){
alert('Adding ' + nQqty  + ' of ' + sItem + '.')
}
```